# Can't see tab bar images

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbar

I can't see the `tabbar` images when i simulate my app.

I tried changing the "render as original image" solution, but it didn't work

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTabBar()
        tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.1255, green: 0.1608, blue: 0.149, alpha: 1)
    }

    func setupTabBar() {

        let homeController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeViewController())
        homeController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "homeglyph_green")
        homeController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "homeglyph_lightgreen")

        let statsController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: StatsViewController())
        statsController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "statsglyph_green")
        statsController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "statsglyph_lightgreen")

        viewControllers = [homeController, statsController]
        guard let items = tabBar.items else { return }
        for item in items {
            item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 4, left: 0, bottom: -4, right: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that your `UIImage(named: "...")` are not nil? try to put a breakpoint or simply print these UIImages

Comment: Make sure your image assets having images with the used names.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Your Image name is same as your store name in Image assets..

if name is same then open Image assets..

1)select Your Image

2) go on Image set

3) change Render As option default to Template Image and run project..

hope fully help this solution..

[image-You can find where you should change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwPJI.png)